# Django Displaying data from GET request

Tags: python, django, response, jinja2

Let's assume that I have a `GET` request the code below show the format of the request

Example :

```
/?title1=xxx&message1=xxx&file1=xxx&...&titleN=xxx&messageN=xxx&fileN=xxx
```

[image]

The example above display the data from the `GET` request.

How could I traverse the list of `GET` request and display each 'requestN' on it's own div.

Of course this using jinja template and django .

I actually find a solution for showing only two parameters .

```
{% for key, value in GET.items %}
        {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}
                {% include "title_snippet.html" with title=value %}
        {% else %}
                {%  include "message_snippet.html" with message=value %}
        {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

This solution display data only for two parameters. But I want it to work for N parameters.

```
?titre1=titre1&?message1=message1&?titre2=titre2&?message2=message2
```

Comment: You may want to normalize data from the GET request into a list of tuples such as `[(title1, message1), (title2, message2), (title3, message3), ...]` and pass that to the template to be rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see this being solved on template side in a easy way. You need to put some logic  while rendering your template.

On your controller side.

```
def myview(request):
    values = []
    for key, value in request.GET.items():
        if key.startswith("title"):
            product = {}
            index_value = key.replace("title","")
            product["title"] = key
            if request.GET.get("message"+index_value):
                product["message"] = request.GET["message"+index_value]
                values.append(product)

    return render_to_response("template.html", {"all_values":values})
```

And on your template side something like

```
{% for value in all_values %}
    <div >
         {% include "title_snippet.html" with title=value.title %}
         {%  include "message_snippet.html" with message=value.message %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You have some problem within your code the first thing is there's a conflict between the forloop value and the value = {} also in the template all_values instead of my_values

Comment: Didn't get the first part. Updated for the second one.

Comment: the for key, value in request.GET.items(): you used the value variable in the 3rd line. on the 4th line you created a Dictionary with the name value = {}

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use regular expressions to sort the request parameters in a iterable dict in your views.py and in the template side you can

```
{% for i in all_values %}
<p>
      {% if 'title' in i.keys.0 %}
                {{ i.values.0 }}
      {% endif %}
</p>
{% endfor%}
```